# display text when # button is clicked

Tags: android

**I want to display a random generated expression like 2+3= when # is pressed. I have implemented this code but when I press it the application crashes.**

My xml code is:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/randomNumberGen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="45dp" />
```

Java code is:

```
package org.example.question;

import java.util.Random;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    int fnum, snum;


Button one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,zero,minus,hash;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        final Random myRandom = new Random();

        display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.randonNumberGen);

        //Buttons
        one= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_1);
        two= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_2);
        three= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_3);
        four= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_4);
        five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_5);
      six= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_6);
        seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_7);
        eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_8);
        nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_9);
        minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_subtract);
        hash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_hash);


        one.setOnClickListener(this);     two.setOnClickListener(this);     three.setOnClickListener(this); 
        three.setOnClickListener(this);   four.setOnClickListener(this);     five.setOnClickListener(this);
        six.setOnClickListener(this);     seven.setOnClickListener(this);     eight.setOnClickListener(this);
        nine.setOnClickListener(this);     minus.setOnClickListener(this);      hash.setOnClickListener(this);

}

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        View v = null;
        switch(v.getId()){  
        case R.id.keypad_hash:
            display.setText(fnum+"+"+ snum+"=");
             fnum = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 1000)) / 100.0);
             snum = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 1000)) / 100.0);
            break;
        }

     }
    public void requestFocus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

When I click the "#" button the application crashes. Any ideas why?

Comment: are fnum and snum initalised? I can see you declare them but I cannot see where you set them.

Comment: @graham, i set them to fnum=0 and snum=0 and i m using them in the switch statement to generate a randon expression like fnum+snum=

Comment: n i set th value to 0 but its still not working

Answer (score 2):

```
View v = null;
switch(v.getId()){
```

You can't do that. `v` is `null`. Try `switch(arg0.getId())` instead.

EDIT: Also as Graham Smith points out, put the line...

```
display.setText(fnum+"+"+ snum+"=");
```

...AFTER you've generated the random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

OK from the code given you declare

```
int fnum, snum;
```

but they are not set anywhere in code before the point when you call:

```
display.setText(fnum+"+"+ snum+"=");
```

you will probably get an error, however without logs/debug info I cannot tell you. Post them to confirm this.

Edit:

After the display.setText... you then set the values. You should set them then display them.

```
    case R.id.keypad_hash:

         fnum = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 1000)) / 100.0);
         snum = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 1000)) / 100.0);
         display.setText(fnum+"+"+ snum+"=");
        break;
```

Next Edit:

If you are not too fussy about the random int you are creating you could do something like:

```
Random random = new Random();

fnum  = random.nextInt(100);
//nextInt(100) - upto the max value of 100
snum = random.nextInt(100);
```

Comment: also why are you multiplying 1000 then dividing by 100? surely you just want to multiply by 10?

Comment: Because your code wont look as cool if you don't have a lot of arithmetic operators in it. Everyone knows that.

Comment: Jon Skeet would have a fit if he saw that maths - where's the "hide from skeet" button gone?